# electron and createPNGStream

Tags: canvas, electron, fabricjs

i cant get createPngstream to work in electron with fabricjs

Hi i am using fabric to generate static banners
it works fine just using nodejs.

Now my colleague would like to do the same, so i  want to build an
electron app for him to use. But now when i try run the code in electron get this Error

Uncaught TypeError: canvas.createPNGStream is not a function

i can use createPNGStream in electron if i use canvas whitout fabric?
What can i do to fix this?

```
const fs = require('fs')
const fabric = require('fabric').fabric;

let canvas  = new fabric.Canvas(null, { width: 500, height: 500 });

fabric.Image.fromURL(__dirname+'/lime-cat.jpg', function(img) {
  img.set({left: 0, top: 0});
  canvas.add(img);
});
canvas.renderAll();

let tagline = new fabric.Textbox(tagres, {
fontSize: 50,
width:iWidth,
fixedWidth: iWidth,
fill: '#ffffff',
textAlign:'center',
fontFamily:'font90557',
left: canvas.width/2, top: canvas.height/2, originX: 'center', originY: 'top',
lineHeight:0.8,
shadow: 'rgba(0,0,0,1) 4px 4px 4px'      
});  

canvas.add(tagline);
canvas.renderAll();

const out = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/test.png')
const stream = canvas.createPNGStream()
stream.pipe(out)
out.on('finish', () =>  console.log('The PNG file was created.'))
```

Comment: `fabric.StaticCanvas.prototype.createPNGStream = function() {
      var impl = fabric.util.getNodeCanvas(this.lowerCanvasEl);
      return impl && impl.createPNGStream();
    };` try using this.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to simply add this as a comment ... but apparently I need to answer it?! (some very strange SO rules!)

I'm pretty sure **createPNGStream** is a nodejs method *for canvas*.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas#canvascreatepngstream

also quoted in pertinent part from;
http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-4

> All of this simply creates Fabric canvas and renders text object onto it. Now, how to create an image of whatever is rendered on canvas? Using createPNGStream method available right on the canvas instance. **createPNGStream returns Node's stream object**, and can then be output into an image file using on('data'), and writing into the stream corresponding to an image file (fs.createWriteStream()).
>
> **fabric.Canvas#createPNGStream is one of the methods specific to Node**. Everything else works the same — you can still create objects as you usually would, add them on canvas, modify, render, and so on.

the solution seems to be run *node.js*, *node-canvas* and *fabric* on your ***server***. instructions are outlined in http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-4, section titled **Fabric on Node.js**

Comment: This looks like a genuine answer to me _ relevant information and links to support your statement_ all good! When you have enough reputation (50) you'll be able to write comments on other contributors' posts _ Upvoted >; ) In the meantime you may want to check out the other privileges you get as reputation increases here >>> https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges